# using SignalR and angularjs on Asp.Net 4.0

Tags: angularjs, .net-4.0, signalr

I have resorted to asking this question here after ive searched Google for the last two day with no progress. Heres  my challenge : I have an Asp.Net 4.0 application which uses Angularjs{I basically use only Html pages}. I need to integrate SignalR into the project for real time communication.  I have googled and all i see is samples with .Net 4.5  above. I cannot use any of these as my service provider doesnt support .net 4.5 hence would not be able to host the application successfully.

My challenge lies on this line

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(SignalRwithAngular.Startup))]
```

when trying to setup a Startup class. as it complains

```
Error   18  The type or namespace name 'OwinStartupAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I  just need a sample of how to configure my angularjs controller to commincate with  the Hub and how to setup the Startup class for .Net 4.0
Please  note I cannot use .Net 4.5  as its not supported by my host.

Any useful link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much googling,  i finally found a way out 
i totally removed

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(SignalRwithAngular.Startup))]
```

from the startup class

i installed the SignalR 1.1.4 package for .Net 4.0 via nuget

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client -Version 1.1.4
```

in  my  Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {

        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();   // Must be added as the first line
         // Other Configs go here
    }
```

in my Startup.cs

```
public  class Startup
{
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
  {
      app.MapHubs();
  }

}
```

and i confirmed it after building by navigating to

```
http://localhost:port/signalr/hubs
```

everything works fine now....

Answer (score 1):

Have you included Microsoft.Owin as a reference (via NuGet)?

Comment: Yes I have both Microsoft.Owin and using Owin included